# Handling keyboard-input without any input-element. (Xaml, WinRT)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

In my WinRT application it's possible for the user to loop over some strings in a textblock.

```
private void contentGrid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource.Equals(contentGrid) || e.OriginalSource.Equals(contentBlock))
        {                
            ShowNextItem();               
        }
    }
```

When debugging I simply mouse-click to emulate a finger-tapp. But I'd like the user to be able to press the spacebar in order to invoke "ShowNextItem()" if they use a desktop rather than a touch-orientated device.

I know how to write keydown-events for textboxes and tried to make one for my textblock. Curiously enough, all input except tapping is ignored.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Only ways I know are access and accelerator keys. See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868161%28v=win.10%29.aspx#keyboard_shortcuts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a focused element gets keyboard events. You can listen to all input events globally though - check `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown`.

Comment: As it turned out I had to add an "invisible" element that "listens" to the keyboard.

Comment: So why did `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` not work for you?